# How to create nested lists in python?

Tags: python, list, arrays, matrix, nested-lists

I know you can create easily nested lists in python like this:

```
[[1,2],[3,4]]
```

But how to create a 3x3x3 matrix of zeroes?

```
[[[0] * 3 for i in range(0, 3)] for j in range (0,3)]
```

or

```
[[[0]*3]*3]*3
```

Doesn't seem right. There is no way to create it just passing a list of dimensions to a method? Ex:

```
CreateArray([3,3,3])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In case a matrix is actually what you are looking for, consider the numpy package.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html#numpy.zeros

This will give you a 3x3x3 array of zeros:

```
numpy.zeros((3,3,3))
```

You also benefit from the convenience features of a module built for scientific computing.

Comment: Hah, I swear the tuple was there when I typed it... Thanks Jader!

Answer (score 1):

NumPy addresses this problem

[Link](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-d3f8e5fe9b903f3c3b2a5c0dfceb60d71602cf93)

```
>>> a = array( [2,3,4] )
>>> a
array([2, 3, 4])
>>> type(a)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

But if you want to use the Python native lists as a matrix the following helper methods can become handy:

```
import copy

def Create(dimensions, item):
    for dimension in dimensions:
        item = map(copy.copy, [item] * dimension)
    return item
def Get(matrix, position):
    for index in position:
        matrix = matrix[index]
    return matrix
def Set(matrix, position, value):
    for index in position[:-1]:
        matrix = matrix[index]
    matrix[position[-1]] = value
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions are just syntactic sugar for adding expressiveness to list initialization; in your case, I would not use them at all, and go for a simple nested loop.

On a completely different level: **do you think the [n-dimensional array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#arrays-ndarray) of NumPy could be a better approach?**
Although you can use lists to implement multi-dimensional matrices, I think they are not the best tool for that goal.

Answer (score 0):

Or use the nest function defined [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577061-nest-a-flat-list/), combined with repeat(0) from the itertools module:

```
nest(itertools.repeat(0),[3,3,3])
```

Answer (score -3):

Just nest the multiplication syntax:

```
[[[0] * 3] * 3] * 3
```

It's therefore simple to express this operation using [folds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function))

```
def zeros(dimensions):
    return reduce(lambda x, d: [x] * d, [0] + dimensions)
```

Or if you want to avoid reference replication, so altering one item won't affect any other you should instead use copies:

```
import copy
def zeros(dimensions):
    item = 0
    for dimension in dimensions:
        item = map(copy.copy, [item] * dimension)
   return item
```

Comment: The downvotes here are probably because the naive use of `*` on a list creates another reference to the same list, not a new independent list.