# How do I create many matrices inside a loop statement with python?

Tags: python, loops, matrix

I want to create for example n matrices like:

```
m1 = [[0,0],[0,0]]
m2 = [[0,0],[0,0]]
.
.    
mn = [[0,0],[0,0]]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create nested lists in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173087/how-to-create-nested-lists-in-python)

Comment: `res = [[item for item in range(2)] for item in range(10)]`

Comment: That'll create `list`s of `[0, 1]`, not `[0, 0]`. It also has the wrong dimensions (10x2 instead of nx2x2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that will work for you

```
res = [[[0 for item3 in range(2)] for item2 in range(2)] for item1 in range(10)]
print res
```

**Output:**

```
[
 [[0, 0], [0, 0]],
 [[0, 0], [0, 0]],
 [[0, 0], [0, 0]],
 [[0, 0], [0, 0]],
 [[0, 0], [0, 0]],
 [[0, 0], [0, 0]],
 [[0, 0], [0, 0]],
 [[0, 0], [0, 0]],
 [[0, 0], [0, 0]],
 [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
]
```

Basically 10(your n value) arrays with 2x2 lists of zeros.